# Upload files inside server webcontent/upload folder in Struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload, struts2

I want to upload .wav files inside Apache Tomcat server, inside `Webcontent/upload` folder.

How to get path from server, so that I will put that path inside my program for uploading .wav files using Struts framework?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get path from server"? `new File("/the/path/to/uploaded/files")`?

Comment: I'd recommend against uploads to the webapp content; this (a) will not work if you deploy a war, and (b) may be lost on some types of redeploys.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you declare use the configuration/property file and mention the path there instead of hardcoding it in java file, then read it from there. The advantage is that even if decide to change it , you dont have to compile it again. You can just restart the server.

Just for information ,you can also use FileUpload utility provided by struts 2 as interceptor. At least have a look on this. May be you find it usefule.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file struts provide a default interceptor names `fileupload`  interceptor.
 You just need to add this in your `struts.xml` file . 
like this one.

```
<action name="clientlogin"  class="action.client.Clientaction" >

     <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>
      </interceptor-ref>
     <result name ="success">/Registration/clientsuccess.jsp  </result>
 </action>
```

and in action class you can save uploaded file by this code

```
          String filePath ="your location where you wan to save uploadedfile";
         System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
         File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, modelobj.getImagefileFileName());

         FileUtils.copyFile(modelobj.getImagefile(), fileToCreate);
```